# How to pass id dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms on a single page.so same id's on the same page will conflict that's the reason I want to pass id dynamically something like using `this` form current form. I want to validate the all forms currently I wrote like this

```js
$('form#test').on('submit', function(e) {}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="script.php" id="test" novalidate>
  //validation here
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

this form id="test" I want to pass current id in js.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to work around the issue of duplicate `id` attributes, which you should not have. Just use a common `class` on all the forms instead.

Comment: Why not fix your page so your HTML is valid, instead of trying to work around having duplicate IDs?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  yeah. I using the same js for all forms should be in the same page

Comment: That's good - and an ideal case for using a common class as I mentioned above

Comment: I added an answer below to make the HTML and JS logic clearer.

Comment: I do not think that you require either a class nor an id, since you can just put a `submit()` on all and use `this` inside it.

Comment: @Lain How can you please explain me briefly.

Comment: @Husna `$('form').on('submit', function() {/** do something **/})`

Comment: @Husna: The above one. Just use `this` instead of  `do something`or `$(this)` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to work around the issue of duplicate `id` attributes, which you should not have. Just use a common `class` on all the forms instead. If you need to identify which form raised the `submit` event, t gett its child `input` elements, for example, then use the `this` keyword. Try this:

```js
$('.example').on('submit', function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(`You submitted the ${this.id} form!`);

  // validate the form here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="example" method="post" action="script.php" id="foo" novalidate>
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>

<form class="example" method="post" action="script.php" id="bar" novalidate>
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>

<form class="example" method="post" action="script.php" id="fizz" novalidate>
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>

<form class="example" method="post" action="script.php" id="buzz" novalidate>
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: yeah we can use class also but my question is what about if we use id?

Comment: You cannot use the same `id` on multiple elements. It's invalid code.